# Select input tag - make middle date selected on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, usability

I currently have a standard select input for years.  Currently, when clicked, it presents a long list of years from 1900-2000, that require you to scroll down.

Is there a way to make it appear in the middle, when clicked, so that you can scroll up or down?

I hope this makes some sense!

Comment: Do you mean you want a middle value selected by default, or that you want the scroll box to appear above and below the select element, rather than just below it?

Comment: Correct: the scroll box to appear above and below the select element, rather than just below it.

Comment: Would it be ok if it's roughly in the middle? (off by 10 at worst)

Answer (score 2):

use `selected` attribute

```
 <select name="years">
    <option>1900</option>
    <option>1901</option>
    <option>1902</option>
    <option>1903</option>
    <option>1904</option>
    <option selected="selected">1905</option>
    <option>1906</option>
    <option>1907</option>
    <option>1908</option>
    <option>1909</option>
    <option>1910</option>
    </select>
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/tnU4K/

Comment: The huge downside to this approach is that you can't force this input to be required because a valid value will be selected by default.

Comment: @Andy E yes. Another option could be to have a non-year value with a generic text, and when user clicks to be removed by javascript

Answer (score 1):

For a drop down `<select>` element? Not in a standardized, cross browser way.  Some browsers *may* (untested) allow you to manipulate the `scrollTop` property of the select element while the list is visible, but I wouldn't count on it.  The only way to start in the middle is have the middle year selected by default.

Personally, I wouldn't bother.  Most users know that they can type whilst focusing a `<select>` element anyway — I rarely use the mouse to select an option in a drop-down `<select>`.

Answer (score 0):

Make a value somewhere around the middle (maybe 1950) selected by default. When someone clicks the select the selected value will be visible, so you can scroll up or down.

Answer (score 0):

You could always go hog wild and do something like this using jquery:

```
//get number of options
var optCount = $('#example option').length;
//divide by 2 and round up for odd numbers
var midPoint = Math.round(optCount/2);
//select that index item
$("#example option:eq(midPoint)").attr("selected", "selected");
```

I haven't tested but it should work.